# Javascript function names in JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to encode JS function names in JSON?

Answer (score 6):

JSON only has the 7 data types listed on [the homepage for the project](http://json.org/).

- Object
- Array
- String
- Number
- true
- false
- null

All JavaScript function names can be expressed as strings, so you can store one in a string without any further encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but maybe you are talking about namespacing?

A good example of this is: http://www.dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript/

It has the appearance of JSON because JSON is formatted in a similar way. Although, it would not be classed as "encoding" your functions as JSON. But, rather creating functions within a namespaced structure (much like JSON).

Another example of this would be:

```
var YourNameSpace = {}; // This can be whatever

(YourNameSpace.utils = function() { // Function name (utils) can be whatever
    return {
        UtilityFunction:function(){
            // Function Contents
            alert('Im cool');
        },
        AnotherUtility:function(){
            // Functions Contents
            alert('Im cool too');
        },
        AnotherSetOfFunctions:function(){
            return {
                CoolFunction:function(){
                    // Function Contents
                    alert('Im even cooler!')
                }
            }
        }()
    }
}());
```

And to call those javascript functions:

```
YourNameSpace.utils.UtilityFunction(); //returns an alert: Im cool
YourNameSpace.utils.AnotherUtility(); //returns an alert: Im cool too
YourNameSpace.utils.AnotherSetOfFunctions.CoolFunction(); //returns an alert: Im even cooler!
```

So the above has the appearance of JSON as they are practically the same in structure.

Hope this helps, or at least gives you a new way to format your JS.

Comment: This might look vaguely like JSON, but it should be emphasised that this is plain JavaScript and not JSON at all. Any decent JSON parser will choke on this.

Comment: @David Dorward Of course. Edited "it has the appearance of JSON because JSON is formatted in the same way." to reflect that: "It has the appearance of JSON because JSON is formatted in a similar way".

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about function names only, there is no problem as function's name is a string.

But if you are talking about serializing javascript object with member functions, it's not that easy.

However you can use **JSONfn** plugin

http://www.eslinstructor.net/jsonfn/

which lets you to 
stringify/parse javascript objects **with member functions**

Hope this helps,

-Vadim